# Как правильно прописывать путь к файлу в PHP?

Tags: php, path

Как правильно прописывать путь к файлу в PHP?

Так:

`file('../pages/wrapper/langs/'.$this->language.'.txt')`

Или так:

`file('V:\home\maintest3.ru\www\pages\wrapper\langs\'.$this->language.'.txt')`

И какая разница между **обратным /** и  **пионерским** \ слешем?

Comment: Обратный используется в UNIX, прямой в Windows. А использовать относительный или абсолютный путь, решается от задачи. В некоторых случаях нужен строго абсолютный, иногда относительный. Но в общем если предполагается перенос данных с одного место в другое, лучше использовать относительные пути

Comment: Есть еще константа DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR - нужный слеш в зависимости от операционной системы. И кстати, "\" иногда приходится писать как двойной "\\" поскольку это символ экранирования.

Comment: @НикитаВасильченко вообще-то в UNIX используется прямой слэш `/`, в Windows – обратный '\'.

Comment: @Alex78191, да я путаю их названия все время:( Прошу прощения